# Custom UITableViewCell with UITextField editingDidEnd race condition

Tags: delegates, uitableview

I have UITableViewController with Edit/Save button as BarItem. I have a custom cell which displays UITextField in edit mode. I am able to save modified text when I move focus to another cell etc. no problem. However my problem begins when I attempt to modify a field and press Save button that triggers setEditing:NO save etc.  What I believe is happening is a race condition where Save action is triggered before editingDidEnd is processed and as a result I am not saving all of the data.
Any suggestions on how to handle this? Am I to go through all visible cells to save all of the data on save? I can definitely do that, but am I going to get into same problem with scroll and edit button clicked? Is there a better way to flush messaging queue?

Answer (score 0):

Given that I have no takers, I think I am stuck with what I know:

1. in done/save (i.e. setEditing:NO) handling go through all cells and save their data
2. Keep updating data every time there is a change i.e. in Value Changed perhaps
3. attempt using UITextFieldDelegate and textFieldShouldEndEditing but I am not sure this would work since I will probably run into the same problem that I have.

I believe endEditing inside setEditing will solve the problem as it supposed to resign first responders for text fields.